# Sample Mean and Sample Variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a sample of data S obtained by flipping a coin x, where 0 denotes the coin
turned up heads, and 1 denotes that it turned up tails. 
S = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}
What is the sample mean for this data ? Will it be just $$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)/n \;where\;
  x \in S $$

What is the sample variance ? Will it be just $$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - mean)^2/n \;where\;
  x \in S $$

I am not sure about that. Please help
Thanks

Comment: Yes, now it is only arithmetic.

Comment: Usually when finding an estimator you want to find the one with that is unbiased and has least variance. So though $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu)^{2}$ is a candidate it turns out that its biased and $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu)^{2}$ has is best estimator , so this is usually treated as sample variance.

Comment: Here is some more info about this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance